# docker stats showing "--"

Tags: performance, docker, utilization

When running docker stats I see:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O             PIDS
11e22031f0be        --                  -- / --                 --                  -- / --             -- / --               --
f55b3bbf6115        0.00%               26.98 MiB / 7.795 GiB   0.34%               0 B / 0 B           6.728 MB / 0 B        2
ff7800652fa1        0.30%               21.61 MiB / 7.795 GiB   0.27%               0 B / 0 B           16.69 MB / 270.2 MB   9
d422fe2d0f1a        0.12%               14.23 MiB / 7.795 GiB   0.18%               0 B / 0 B           7.055 MB / 0 B        5
86df65e7c195        0.04%               6.141 MiB / 7.795 GiB   0.08%               0 B / 0 B           6.192 MB / 0 B        2
1d0c20d5ea48        0.27%               32.51 MiB / 7.795 GiB   0.41%               0 B / 0 B           23.48 MB / 0 B        11

         --
```

Does anyone know what the -- indicates? The container is running and I can view the non-zero per-process statistics using top. What does the -- mean?

The result of docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
11e22031f0be        aaaaaaaaaaa                  "run master"             28 hours ago        Up 28 hours                             agitated_bhaskara
f55b3bbf6115        bbbbbbbbb                    "run ovn-controller"     28 hours ago        Up 28 hours                             ovn-controller
ff7800652fa1        quay.io/coreos/etcd:v3.0.2   "/usr/local/bin/etcd "   28 hours ago        Up 28 hours                             etcd
d422fe2d0f1a        ccccc/ovs                    "run ovs-vswitchd"       28 hours ago        Up 28 hours                             ovs-vswitchd
86df65e7c195        ddddd/ovs                    "run ovsdb-server"       28 hours ago        Up 28 hours                             ovsdb-server
1d0c20d5ea48        eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee             "abcde minino"           28 hours ago        Up 28 hours                             minion
```

Comment: Post `docker ps` and your `docker stat`

Comment: Please see edits. thanks.

Comment: Container 11e looks frozen!

Comment: I don't think that was the problem. I exec-ed into the bash script of the container and it was running fine.

Comment: What `docker top 11e` shows?

Comment: maybe related https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21848

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, except all of my containers are in the `--` state.